# Как использовать отступы других окон?

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Text в ViewPager не двигается. А фрагменты двигаются. Задача такая что надо расположить фрагменты таким образом чтобы текст ASD был над TEXT. Во всех фрагментах.

Конечно можно рассчитать и по DP установить значения. Но проблема в указании статических значений в том что если запустить на другом макете то это выглядит ужасно и ASD налезает на TEXT.

Используя ReleativeLayout или ConstaintLayout можно избежать этого в том случае если View компоненты лежат в одном XML макете. А как быть в таком случае?

Есть идеи какие нибудь?

P.S. Предложения типа установить все VIew в один макет и после менять текст не подойдет, нужна анимация ViewPager

Comment: Вариант не делать `ViewPager` высотой на всю страницу, а сделать ниже текста ASD, не подходит? Выше в нём тоже есть какой-то контент?

Comment: @eugeneek, Подходит. Но блин вся проблема в Backgoorund. У фрагментов на весь экран Картинка. В этом и проблема

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у Вас они одинаковые, можете в нужных layout добавить View с нулевыми размерами по центру и позиционировать текст относительно нее:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/view" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/view" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Если необходимо несколько сдвинуть относительно центра задавайте для первого

```
android:layout_marginTop=" больше 0dp"
```

для второго

```
android:layout_marginTop=" меньше 0dp"
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]